# How do I get the date from a datepicker using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, variables, datepicker

How do I get the date from a jquery UI datepicker like the month and save the value of it in a variable in php?

I've seen a lot of things like this `<div id="calendar"></div>` and I don't understand.

Thanks.

Here's my code

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#from" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
var day1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();  
var month1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();  
var year1 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getYear();
}
});
$( "#to" ).datepicker({
defaultDate: "+1w",
changeMonth: true,
numberOfMonths: 1,
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
var day2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getDate();  
var month2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getMonth();  
var year2 = $(this).datepicker('getDate').getYear();
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<label for="from"> FROM </label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to"> TO </label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="to" name="to">
<input type="submit" name="boton" value="  Submit ">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to post the form as you normally would and retrieve the passed value with `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the type of the request.

Comment: What did you just do?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" value="26-10-15" />
```

**PHP**

if it has isset submit denotes that the submit the form

```
<?php if($_REQUEST['datepicker'])){    
echo $_POST['datepicker'];    
}   ?>
```

Comment: What if there is set `submit`, but not `datepicker`

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply datepicker to input field like

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>" name="selectedDate"/>
```

Than in PHP just check value from `$_GET` or `$_POST`:

```
$selectedDate = isset($_REQUEST['selectedDate']) ? $_REQUEST['selectedDate'] : null;
```

---

You have HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="to" name="to">
```

For that you call datepicker:

```
$( "#to" ).datepicker({/* ... */});
```

Now all you need to do is:

Wrap your input fields with `<form action="mySubmitScript.php" method="post"></form>` add additionally `<input type="submit" value="submit">`

In PHP you do:

```
if (isset($_POST['to'])) {
    $to = $_POST['to'];
}
```

You can submit form without reloading page using `$.ajax()` jQuery method.